# Should I cache dlsym's return value?

Tags: c, performance, posix, dynamic-linking, dlsym

I'm using the POSIX `dlopen`/`dlsym` API's to load dynamic libraries at runtime and then call functions from those libraries by name.

Is it a good idea, performance-wise, to store the result of `dlsym` somewhere? Or does dlsym do its own caching already and would adding another layer be useless or even detrimental? Functions could potentially be called many, many times, but I don't really have a way of knowing in advance which ones, or how often they will be called.

Thanks!

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Don't do anything until you *see* dlsym causing problems.

Comment: I think you should remember the value, but it has nothing to do with performance. It just makes sense that setup code figures out the function pointers you need, and later the code just calls them.

Comment: @ugoren: Sadly, I don't know in advance which functions will be used (I don't even know which libraries they will be coming from).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dlsym` function does not do any caching. It is simply accessing the ELF symbol tables (using its hash table, which is not very well implemented).

I think you should avoid calling `dlsym` on the same name and library a lot of times (e.g. millions of times).

You might use lazy techniques: put e.g. the name & library used in your `dlsym` calls together (in some of your structure or class) with the `dlsym`-ed function pointer, and call `dlsym` only when that pointer is null.

You also might want to catch `dlsym` failure as quickly as possible.

FWIW, you can call `dlopen` and `dlsym` a lot of times. In particular, you can have many dozens of thousands of `dlopen`-ed shared libraries on Linux, as my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) example demonstrates. But avoid `dlclose`-ing a library if you still have an active call frame for some `dlsym`-ed function inside. Actually, you might never call `dlclose` and your program would still work (with a slight process address space leak).